# Android - getNetworkInterface and needed permissions

Tags: android, networking, permissions

got a strange problem here.

I have a function which reads the NetworkInterfaces and gets me the WiFi-Interface name.
This worked properly 2 weeks ago with the only permission "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE".

This week i mainly tested with 3G and did some minor changes to the overall code and today i noticed 'NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()' doesnt work anymore, giving me a "permission denied" exception. Few secs later my dear friend google tells me i need INTERNET permission...

-> I never ever used INTERNET permission in this project ???

So what could be wrong? Any way to get the NetworkInterfaces without using the internet permissions? It works again if i add it but idont really want to use it just for that.

```
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = null;
    try {
        interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: any solution for this problem ? I am facing same problem

Comment: @Saby, or in case anyone coming, I got the value after using the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`